# Movie Identification: Police chase in a SF movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

Based in the future. The only scene I remember is that the guy is running away from the police. As the police are chasing him (in a tunnel-like environment), the cost of the chase (i.e. the fuel cost of the police vehicle) is being discounted from the guy's bank account online realtime. He's aware of this and is trying to keep up the chase till his account runs out and the police stops, 'cause it's not feasible to go after him anymore!

Comment: Can you remember when you saw this? Was it new at the time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds very similar to THX 1138. One of George Lucas' early films from 1971.

Robert Duvall plays THX 1138, one of many humans with alphanumeric names living in underground cities run by automated systems and policed by droid officers to "keep the peace" after the surface of Earth has become uninhabitable.

In the end of the film, he steals a police jet car, crashes it, climbs up a tunnel (like you described) with the police droids chasing him up the ladder. However, then the police HQ sees the expense of chasing THX 1138 as going above-budget and decide to call off the chase last-minute due to the computer making him "financially infeasible" to continue chasing.

Link to the synopsis here: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066434/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ql_stry_2#synopsis

The only difference with this film from what you describe is: it's not coming from his bank account, it's coming from the city's budget allocations for each citizen. The cities practice near totalitarian control over the citizens.

Link to the clip that sounds similar to what you are describing:

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!